# Dynamic conditional cumulative sum using multiple columns in Scala Spark and window partitioning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning, lag, cumulative-sum

I want to apply capping on a dataset that was previously uncapped, and measure the impact on number of times a shopper could have purchased an item when the capping feature is enabled. Imagine there is now a cap of 3 purchases per 3 days for each customer to buy an item. Before capping was applied, the purchases could go up to any amount. We want to counterfactually apply the capping on the offline dataset (the first 3 columns below). I'd like to calculate the last column (`cappedPurchases`) based on the first three columns. Any ideas are appreciated. Here is an example:

```
+----+---+------------+---------------+
|user|day|numPurchases|cappedPurchases|
+----+---+------------+---------------+
|  U1|  1|           2|              2|
|  U1|  2|           5|              1|
|  U1|  3|           3|              0|
|  U1|  4|           0|              0|
|  U1|  5|           4|              3|
|  U1|  6|           1|              0|
|  U1|  7|           6|              0|
+----+---+------------+---------------+
```

Calculating `cappedPurchases` requires a cumulative sum of `numPurchases` conditioned on whether it has reached the cap, effectively it requires a cumulative sum of the column itself (`cappedPurchases`) as it is being formed. Not sure if Spark has a builtin function to help with this.

More details: On first day, customer has purchased the item 2 times, and since that is less than the cap (3 per 3 days), that is acceptable (so, cappedPurchases=numPurchases=2). On second day, they have purchased it 5 times, but that is beyond the cap and only 1 purchase is acceptable (cappedPurchases=1). On third day, since the customer's cumulative sum in the past 3 days has already reached the cap, none of the purchases on that day would be accepted when capping is enabled. And so on.

I tried to use a udf on a `collect_list(day,numPurchases)` columns, but that was slow.

Comment: On 5th day why is only 1 purchase accepted? Previuos two days were without accepted purchase, so if I understood the logic here 3 should be fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was a typo.

Comment: If udf wasn't good, try [udaf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html). I don't think you can make it with raw SQL.